# Getting concurrent requests processing issue with Redis+PHP

Tags: phpredis

> I am using PHP 5.3 I am using Redis, to store PHP array data for every
>   requests in Redis variable. I am setting value for 1 redis variable
>   and on every request I am incrementing value by 1. Using that value as
>   key for the each array element. But on concurrent requests its
>   creating problem - 1) Its skipping few records in between. 2) Value of
>   varible is getting stored as key is getting duplicated.
>
> Right now I am using "Predis" as PHP+Redis client.  Please help me in
>   this and let me know how can I achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using set (or sorted set) instead? You don't need to worry about managing an external index as its automatically done by Redis.